# Condition query on the join

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have a Rent class who contain a list a payment.

I would like to find to rent with paymentDue or with empty payment

So if a rent don't have any roompayment, i would like to get it.
Also if there are roomPayment and contain a paymentDueDate and the date in parameter is after the paymentDueDate, if there are not other roomPayment after it, i would like to get it.

Is it possible to do it in JPA or i need to get data and parse it with Java?

```
@Entity
public class Rent {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long rentId;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "rent")
    private List<RoomPayment> roomPaymentList;

    private LocalDate fromDate;

    private LocalDate toDate;
    ...
}

@Entity
public class RoomPayment {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long roomPaymentId;

    @OneToOne
    private PaymentType paymentType;

    private BigDecimal amountReceived;

    private LocalDate paymentDueDate;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "rent_id")
    private Rent rent;
    ...
}
```

I created this query but it's not complete

```
@Query("select r from Rent r where r.roomPaymentList is empty and r.fromDate <= :date and r.toDate >= :date")
public List<Rent> findLateRentPayment(@Param("date") LocalDate date);
```

Edit

Actually, this query generate this

```
select
    rent0_.rent_id as rent_id1_33_,
    rent0_.bail_id as bail_id4_33_,
    rent0_.from_date as from_dat2_33_,
    rent0_.to_date as to_date3_33_ 
from
    rent rent0_ 
where
    not (exists (select
        roompaymen1_.room_payment_id 
    from
        room_payment roompaymen1_ 
    where
        rent0_.rent_id=roompaymen1_.rent_id)) 
    and rent0_.from_date<=? 
    and rent0_.to_date>=?
```

If i have theses data

```
rent
rentId | fromDate | toDate
1      | 2015-12-08 | 2015-12-15
2      | 2015-12-08 | 2015-12-15
3      | 2015-12-08 | 2015-12-15

roompayment

roomPaymentId   | rentId    |   paymentDueDate
1               | 1         |
3               | 3         |   2015-12-14
```

Query should return 2 and 3

2 because rent don't have any roomPaymentId
3 because have a roomPayment with paymentDueDate but they don't have any other roomPayment after this one

Answer (score 0):

```
select r from Rent r 
left join r.roomPaymentList payment
where payment.paymentDueDate < :date
or r.roomPaymentList is empty
```

It will return rents containing no payment and rents containing any payment which the due date is before a parameter date. Don't know if this is the result set that you want.